# controlgroup: icons not shown on headers in JQM 1.4

Tags: jquery-mobile

On version 3.1 I could see icons on headers embebed in 'controlgroups', now with versions 4.0 or 4.1 they does´n show.

```
    <div data-role='header' data-position='fixed' data-theme='b'>

        <div data-role='controlgroup' class='ui-btn-right' data-type='horizontal'>
          <a href='#Pag_Audita' class='ui-btn ui-icon-grid ui-btn-inline'>Regs</a>
          <a href='#Pag_Info' class='ui-btn ui-icon-gear ui-btn-inline'>Info</a>
          <button onclick ='Refresh()' class='ui-btn ui-icon-refresh ui-btn-inline'>Update</button>
        </div>

        <h1 class='ui-title' role='heading'></h1>

    </div>
```

Is there any deprecation thing that I am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `ui-btn-inline` in a controlgroup, so remove that and add `ui-btn-icon-left` or `ui-btn-icon-right` depending where you want the icon to show:

```
<div data-role='controlgroup' class='ui-btn-right' data-type='horizontal'>
    <a href='#Pag_Audita' class='ui-btn ui-icon-grid ui-btn-icon-left'>Regs</a>
    <a href='#Pag_Info' class='ui-btn ui-icon-gear ui-btn-icon-left'>Info</a>
    <button onclick ='Refresh()' class='ui-btn ui-icon-refresh ui-btn-icon-left'>Update</button>
</div>
```